# How to to create a branch policy (or similar) in azure devops which forces extra reviewers on custom conditions

Tags: git, azure-devops, policies

I want to add extra reviewers to a pull request if the changeset breaks some custom rules.

I know I can add extra reviewers if certain files are touched. But in our case if we see certain things in any changed file (for instance certain columns are touched in our database), then extra reviewers are added.

In [use Azure Functions to create custom branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=azure-devops) I can see that you can create custom policies but how can you add extra reviewers from the rules therein?

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, but I've had this answer on twitter https://twitter.com/AbelSquidHead/status/1173245232734851075?s=19

Comment: Glad you have got the help. Do you mind convert it into answer then accept it after you test it successfully? If still have issue, just feel free to share it, thus we could help you further:-)

Comment: THanks @MerlinLiang-MSFT - I will once I've coded a working solution. That was why I left a comment as soon as I got it and am working on building this out.

Comment: Wonderful! Appreciate this in advance:-)